# Get Index of row in GridView based on value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, indexing

I have following problem:

I am using .NET 3.5 to develop an application for Windows CE, and to display tabular data, I use DataGrid class. I use RowFilter to display only selected rows, as:

```
//docRows = some DataTable
dgDocRow.DataSource = docRows;
docRows.DefaultView.RowFilter = "WHERE ID > 1"
```

Now I have user imput, such as Name = "some text". I wish to know index of row in DataGrid, where column Name has value "some text".

I can easily get index of that row in original DataSource of DataGrid, but displayed rows are filtered and therefore displayed index is different from index in original data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, zbynek

Comment: you can take Id as a column and hide it and use it when user selects the row

Comment: I am afraid that would not solve my issue. User does not select a row - he enters value (through barcode scanner), and I want to select the row with that value.

Comment: so you have saved scanner id differently ? if so you can map with that .

Comment: the procedure is as follows: I have datagrid with some data, which are filtered. I scan some code (ie. "ABC123") and find ID of "ABC123" in original datasource. Now I want to select row in DataGrid with given ID - but index of row in DataGrid is different from the one in original DataSource, because DataGrid is filtered

Comment: can you post some code here so I can have better understanding ?